# How can a function with no parameters all of a sudden take parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, parameters

I come from a c background so I'm used to being a bit more pedantic with syntax, but I'm having a hard time getting my head around whats happening here. D3.js has a function called scaleLinear. They give an example on how to use it.

```
var myScale = d3.scaleLinear();

myScale
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, 800]);

myScale(0);    // returns 0
myScale(50);   // returns 400
myScale(100);  // returns 800
```

How does myscale suddenly take a parameter, and where is it going?

Comment: Apart from that code saying nothing about how many parameters `myScale` is supposed to take, welcome to javascript: `function f() { console.log(arguments.length); }; f("JS", "does", "not", "care", { penguins: 5 });`

Comment: source of d3.scaleLinear: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/src/linear.js#L62

Comment: `arguments` maybe?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans so the function is returning a different function that takes parameter?

Comment: Correct. And functions are just objects, so can be assigned other functions as properties (as per Collin's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if I'm off-base here, but it seems like you're particularly interested in how `myScale` is used both as a function `myScale(0)` as well as `myScale.domain(...)`.

In JS, functions are just objects that can be invoked with the `()` syntax. Sometimes it's convenient to do something like this:

```
// contrived example
function talk(message) { console.log(message); }
talk.yell = function(message) { console.log(message.toUpperCase()) }
```

now if you `talk("foo"); // "foo"`, and if you `talk.yell("foo"); // "FOO"`.

So in your case, the `scaleLinear` function, returned a function (`myScale`) that also has other helpers on it such as `.domain(...)`, `.range(...)` (side note: it's likely that `domain` and `range` return `this` to allow for that kind of chaining, but technically it's the result of `.domain()` that has `.range()` invoked on it)

There's obviously more useful cases for this pattern. For example, it's common for modules to export a function and then include additional helpers or classses as members of that function. `requestjs` uses this pattern to provide a basic `request(...)` function along with the rest of its features.

This is also how static class methods work in JS.

```
function Point(x, y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
Point.fromPolar = function(r, t) { . . . }

var point = new Point(0, 1);
var samePoint = Point.fromPolar(1, 0.5 * Math.PI);
```

So let's do an example of how your specific example might be working.

```
const d3 = {};
d3.scaleLinear = function() {
    const result = function(num) { /* logic here to handle myScale(n) */ }
    result.domain = function(...) { ...; return result; }
    result.range = function(...) { ...; return result; }
}
```

You can see, there need be no relation between the arguments of `scaleLinear` and the result function that is returned from it.

Moreover, there really isn't nearly as strict of a notion in js about taking in arguments. JS doesn't check calls, so all arguments are always optional unless enforced in the function itself.

The following runs fine:

```
function doSomething() {}; doSomething(1); doSomething(1, 2, 3);
function doSomething2(n) {}; doSomething2(); doSomething2(1, 2, 3);
function doSomething3(...nums) {}; doSomething3(); doSomething3(1,2,3);
```

Comment: So `var myScale` became the function `myScale(num)` because scaleLinear() returned a function `func(num)` ?

Comment: That's about it, yep.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at it wrong. `var myScale = d3.scaleLinear();` stores the result of `d3.scaleLinear()` in a variable called `myScale`.

This isn't different from doing something like:

```
int i = myFunc();
```

On C. However, it just so happens that `d3.scaleLinear();` returns a function (a specific function that takes one parameter and scales it). So if you do `var myScale = d3.scaleLinear();`, now there's a function being stored in `myScale` that takes one parameter.

You can read more about `d3.scaleLinear()` [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scalelinear).

Comment: Pretty sure he's asking about the fact that he can do both `myScale.domain(...)` _as well as_ `myScale(1)`.